# using if elseif else with different variables instead of if block

Tags: php

I can use if elseif with different variables instead of if() block?

```
if(empty($firstname)){

 }
if(empty($lastname)){

 }
 if(empty($password)){  

 }
if(!empty($firstname) || !empty($lastname) || !empty(password){ 

  }
```

i can use this instead of if block?

```
if(empty($firstname)){

 }elseif(empty($lastname)){

 }elseif(empty($password)){

 else{

  }
```

Comment: Yes You Can use

Comment: **if statement** - executes some code if one condition is true

**if...else statement** - executes some code if a condition is true and another code if that condition is false

**if...elseif....else statement** - executes different codes for more than two conditions

Comment: you have to try it out first. If it doesn't work, come back with the error(s)

Comment: else if more than 3 times use still applicable?

Comment: i use more than 4  elseif because in some example there is only 1 if 1 elseif and 1 else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does two distinct things -

The first will consist of 4 if statements, the first 3 will check if each individual field is empty.  This allows you to set an error message to say a particular field is empty.  The last test will only run the block when all 3 fields have something in them.

The second piece of code will only trigger one of all the 4 blocks of code.  So it may say that `$firstname` is empty or second name.  BUT this won't let you validate all of the fields and say if each one is empty.

In **this** example, you would probably want the first one which checks each field and only does the final block if all fields are filled.

Although it should be noted that your if condition in the first case may be wrong...

```
if(!empty($firstname) || !empty($lastname) || !empty(password){
```

Should probably be...

```
if(!empty($firstname) && !empty($lastname) && !empty(password){
```

This says if all fields are not empty (so all contain something), your existing version works if any field is not empty (the difference between || and &&).

Comment: in the if elseif else statement, i can use 3 or 4 times the elseif because in some example there is only 1 if and 1 elseif 1 else?

Comment: Using `elseif` allows you to chain as many tests as you want - BUT only one will be executed.

Comment: it is possible to omit else in if else statement?

Comment: An if...else... statement without an else is just an if... statement.